# How to get the fbid of the last poster in a group? (PHP Facebook API)

Tags: php, facebook, api

I have a script that sends a post to my group.

```
$attachment = array('message' => $message, 'link' => $link );
try 
    $result = $facebook->api("/$sendTo/feed/",'post', $attachment);

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
echo "error";
}
```

$sendTo holds the fbid of the group,

What's the code that needs to be added so that the script checks the group and if the last post (most recent one) was made by my fbid ($myfbid) then don't post the message?

any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the code that needs to be added so that the script checks the group and if the last post (most recent one) was made by my fbid ($myfbid) then don't post the message?

I’d suggest using FQL,

```
SELECT actor_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = '{group_id}'
  ORDER BY created_time LIMIT 1
```

Ordering by created_time plus limiting to 1 gives you info about only the latest post, and the actor_id is what we are interested in here, because that’s the account that made the post. (source_id is, according to docs, *“[t]he ID of the user, page, group, or event whose wall the post is on”*.)

You could evalute actor_id and compare it to your id – or you do the comparison right there in the FQL query,

```
SELECT actor_id = me() FROM …
```

This will return a value with the key `anon` (for *anonymous result*, I guess – there’s no “aliases” in FQL as we know them from SQL), and a value of true or false.

Comment: Thanks! looks good - if this was to be executed with a PHP for loop for lets say 80 groups - would that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, that will surely be a problem, if you do them one-by-one, because that’ll mean 80 HTTP requests. In that case you should combine them to one Multi-Query, so that you’ll get all the data with one request.

Comment: Multi-queries are explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/